# When uploading a large file to a my filezilla ftp server, my connection drops and my upload is stopped, how can I fix this?

Tags: ftp, filezilla

Based on some research, I think this could be due to the fact that my router drops a port connection when a port has been idle for a specific amount of time. However, I'm not sure if this is the problem for sure, but if it is, how would I go about fixing it?

Comment: I've seen something similar.. and this may be anecdotal evidence, but what I did to ensure it did not cut off, is to rate-limit the upload. So if you got upload bandwidth of 1MBps, rate-limit the FTP upload speed to.. say 0.8Mbps and at least it will be steady and does not cut off (although a bit slower).

Comment: What do the server level logs show around this time (just before, during, and just after)? That'd be a good starting point as well as any client level logs. Look at turning on verbose logging for BOTH if you look and do not see applicable detail logged in case you need to turn on advanced logging to capture the correlated traffic.